# Can't listen to emitted event from child component on the parent component

Tags: vue.js

I have two components set up like this

`FirstComponent.vue`

```
<template>
  <second-component @click="doThis" />
</template>
```

`SecondComponent.vue`

```
<template>
  <img @click="doThisSecond" />
<template/>
```

While `doThisSecond` does work, `doThis` will not fire.

I also tried to do `this.$emit('componentClicked')` from `doThisSecond()` but I can't catch the event from `FirstComponent.vue`

Am I missing something?

Comment: try @click.native="doThis" instead of @click="doThis"

Comment: Which template contains the doThis method click handler?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisLi that solved the problem! Though not sure why the `$on` didn't catch the `$emit`.

Comment: you used this.$emit('componentClicked') so you need to catch it with @componentClicked

Comment: @ChrisLi shouldn't I be able to do `this.$on('componentClicked', () => { // handle event })` in the parent component? This doesn't work.

Comment: I never used it this way, but based on document here https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on my guess is $on only catches events $emit from itself, not it's children components.

Comment: The `click` event was alredy handled inside the nested `second-component` and does not bubble up any further. Therefore you can not catch it again on the outer component.

You can emit another event inside the inner components click handler and catch it on the outer component.

Comment: @andypotato " You can emit another event inside the inner components click handler and catch it on the outer component. " That's what I was trying to do and it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

### Syntax and use methods

FirstComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <second-component @doThisSecond="doThis" />
</template>
```

SecondComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <img @click="this.$emit("doThisSecond")" />
<template/>
```

You can use methods to send data

```
<template>
  <img @click="emitDoThis" />
<template/>

<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
      person: {
        name: 'Hello',
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    emitDoThis() {
      this.$emit('doThisSecond', this.person.name);
    }
  }
</script>
```